# Traducir fragmento de código de matlab a Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, matlab, plot

Tengo un código en matlab cuyo objetivo es realizar un gráfico a partir de unos arrays por medio de la iteración de los parámetros i,j. Me preguntaba si alguien sabía cómo traducir esto a Python, sobre todo la parte del plot que es la que más se me ha complicado.

Este es el fragmento de código de matlab:

```
ni=3;
net = 112;  
xee=zeros(ni,2);

for i=1:net
    for j=1:ni
        xe(3*nee(i,j)-2); 
        xe(3*nee(i,j)-1);    
        plot3(xe(3*nee(i,j)-2),xe(3*nee(i,j)-1),0.0,'s','MarkerEdgeColor','b','MarkerSize',10,
 'MarkerFaceColor',[1 1 1])
        hold on
        xee(j,1)=xe(3*nee(i,j)-2);
        xee(j,2)=xe(3*nee(i,j)-1);
    end

face = [1 2 3];
patch('Faces',face,'Vertices',xee,'EdgeColor','red','FaceColor','none','LineWidth',1);    

end
```

Donde **xe** y **nee** son dos arrays (Adjunto en un excel los dos arrays en el link de Wetransfer. En la hoja 1 está **xe** y en la hoja 2 **nee**)

De momento yo he traducido lo siguiente, pero como ya mencioné, la parte del plot está muy complicada y está mala:

```
ni = 3
net = 112
xee = np.zeros((ni,2))

for i in range(net):
    for j in range(ni):
    
        xe[int(3*nee[i, j] - 3)]
        xe[int(3*nee[i, j] - 2)]
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
        ax.plot_surface(xe[int(3*nee[i, j] - 3)], xe[int(3*nee[i, j] - 2)], np.zeros((1,1)),  
cmap=cm.coolwarm)
        plt.show()
        xee[j, 0] = xe[int(3*nee[i, j]- 3)]
        xee[j, 1] = xe[int(3*nee[i, j] - 2)] 

    face = 1, 2, 3
    plt.patch('Faces',face,'Vertices',xee,'EdgeColor','red','FaceColor','none','LineWidth',1)
```

[Enlace para descargar los arrays **xe** y **nee**](https://we.tl/t-xAj8SqgcBM)

la idea del código de matlab es graficar la distribución de los puntos almacenados en xe, donde el eje **x** es, por ejemplo para la primera iteración de matlab cuando i=j=1,

```
Ejex = xe(3*nee(i,j)-2) = xe(3*nee(1,1)-2) = xe(3*33-2) = xe(97) = 260.956029669067
```

Y el eje **y** para la primera iteración sería:

```
Ejey = xe(3*nee(i,j)-1) = xe(3*nee(1,1)-1) = xe(3*33-1) = xe(98) = 89.9995011257129
```

La idea es ir graficando cada uno de los puntos sin borrar el anterior. En matlab me da esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y si en vez de pedir traducir de matlab a python explicas qué se supone que hace matlab y qué resultado esperas? De ese modo quien conozca python pero no matlab podrá ayudar también.

Comment: Hola abulafila! He añadido la información a la pregunta de lo que estoy buscando, que es básicamente graficar los puntos almacenados en el array **xe**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intentar una traducción directa del código Matlab a python no es lo mejor en este caso.

Ya que tienes los datos en una excel, puedes beneficiarte de la biblioteca `pandas` para leerlos:

```
import pandas as pd

xe = pd.read_excel("anexo.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name="xe")
nee = pd.read_excel("anexo.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name="nee")
```

Una vez los tenemos leídos, hay que procesarlos como deseas antes de pintarlos. Aquí es donde la cosa se vuelve un poco confusa, pues el código Matlab que pones no lo entiendo (y tampoco su traducción a Python), pues pareces estar queriendo pintar una superficie 3D por un lado, pero en realidad un *scatter plot* por otro.

Voy a darte la implementación de lo que he entendido que quieres hacer.

Entiendo que la hoja `nee` contiene en realidad índices a coordenadas que están en la hoja `xe`, pero que deben ser transformados, con la fórmula que has indicado: multiplicar por 3 el valor encontrado en `nee` y restar 3 para obtener el índice de la coordenada `x` deseada, o bien restar 2 para obtener el de la coordenada `y` deseada. Estos índices se usan sobre el vector guardado en `xe` para extraer los valores `x,y` a plotear.

Pandas permite hacer operaciones "vectoriales", esto es, que operan con todos los valores de una columna "a la vez" (en realidad internamente pandas itera por esos valores, pero tu código python no necesita bucles, sino que usa una sintaxis "vectorial").

Es decir, podríamos agregar al dataframe `nee` un par de columnas adicionales que serían los índices a usar en `xe` para sacar `x` e `y`, con solo dos líneas de código:

```
nee["ix"] = nee.iloc[:,0]*3-3
nee["iy"] = nee.iloc[:,0]*3-2
```

Aquí, `nee.loc[]` permite acceder a elementos concretos de la tabla `ne` según sus coordenadas. Por ejemplo `nee.iloc[i,j]` iría al elemento de la fila `i`, columna `j`. Pero también permite acceder a "columnas completas" de una sola vez, si en el índice de la fila pones `:`. Así pues `nee.iloc[:,0]` extrae la columna 0 completa.

Como ves esa columna se usa en la operación `*3-3`, y pandas multiplicará por 3 y restará 3 a *todos* los elementos de esa columna. El resultado lo guardamos en una columna nueva que hemos llamado `ix` (por "índices de x"). Análogamente computamos la columna nueva `iy` ("índices de y").

Una vez tenemos éstas, podemos extraer las coordenadas `x` necesarias de la tabla `xe` con esta sintaxis:

```
x = xe.iloc[nee.ix]
y = xe.iloc[nee.iy]
```

De nuevo esto es una operación "vectorial", que actúa sobre toda la tabla "a la vez". El resultado es que tanto `x` como `y` son  vectores columna, que se pueden usar ya directamente en un plot: `plt.scatter(x, y)`.

### Todo junto

Ahora bien, la tabla `nee` tiene tres columnas, y ahí es donde me pierdo. Aparentemente en tu código no distingues de ninguna forma de qué columna vienen los datos, y te limitas a iterar por ellas.

Para mayor claridad yo voy a iterar también sobre las tres columnas (0, 1 y 2) de la tabla `nee`, pero voy a usar un color diferente (y una leyenda diferente) para los puntos extraídos de cada columna.

El código completo sería entonces:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

xe = pd.read_excel("anexo.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name="xe")
nee = pd.read_excel("anexo.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name="nee")

for i in range(3):
  nee["ix"] = nee.loc[:,i]*3-3
  nee["iy"] = nee.loc[:,i]*3-2
  x = xe.iloc[nee.ix]
  y = xe.iloc[nee.iy]
  plt.scatter(x, y, label=f"Column {i}", marker="s")

plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10,4)
plt.legend()
```

Y este es el resultado:

[image: Resultado]

Como ves, los puntos azules (de la columna 0) no se ven, entiendo que porque quedan tapados por los verdes.

## Bonus

Otra versión **aún más breve** si realmente no quieres separar por colores las columnas.

En ese caso no necesitamos ni siquiera iterar por esas columnas, y podemos aplicar la transformación `*3-3` a la tabla completa, o mejor a sus valores. El resultado será otra tabla (de 112x3 como la tabla original) en la que los valores ya están multiplicados por 3 y restados. Mediante la función `.reshape(-1)` podemos convertir esa matriz de 112x3 a un solo vector de 336 elementos, que podemos usar como índices sobre `xe`.

Podemos usar pandas para leer la excel, pero seguidamente extraer solo la matriz de valores (con `.values`). El resultado es un array numpy, que nos permite una sintaxis más corta al evitar tener que usar `iloc`.

Todo el código se reduce ahora a **tres líneas**:

```
xe = pd.read_excel("anexo.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name="xe").values
nee = pd.read_excel("anexo.xlsx", header=None, sheet_name="nee").values
plt.scatter(xe[(nee*3-3).reshape(-1)], xe[(nee*3-2).reshape(-1)])
```

Lo que produce la gráfica:

[image: Grafica]